# symfony2 money field doesn't story comma into database

Tags: symfony

I used the field "money" in my product entity to store the price of a product in euros.

```
   ->add('pRetailPrize' ,'money', array(
         'currency' => 'EUR',
        'divisor' => 100,

        ))
```

It shows the price in euros (ex 1300,35 €) when you retrive or insert a price through the money entity field, but when you have to show the price using getRepository:

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:ProductInfo')->find($id);
```

And the you pass the variable $entity (entity.pRetailPrize) to a twig it doesn't show the comma before decimals. I then realized it didn't save the comma into the database. Is there a way to save the comma into database using the money field or to use the money field in a way it shows the comma when you retrieve a price from the database in euro currency system using getRepository as shown above? Also any solution or suggestion to do it differently is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

And it shouldn't. Comma separation is a output thing and, because of the localization's specifics, it should not be stored persistently.

In order to print it, you should use built-in `number_format` filter: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/number_format.html

**Example:**

```
{{ number|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I tried that solution but on the database, using the money field, it doesn't store any comma or dot. So if I insert in the money field the price 1328,56 € it simply store 132856, without any punctuation. Then I don't understand the reason of money field, it does nothing, I should simply use "text" or "null" in the form field and on the database decimal.

Comment: I believe the only purpose of that is formatting and client validation. Nothing else really...

Answer (score 0):

There is only one thing: you set field mapping as `integer` instead of `float` in your entity.

Comment: Yes, I did it. I just need to find a way to put in the price field a number with  comma which is automatically converted in dot when stored in the database, and the contrary when it's retrieved from database.

Comment: In Twig `{{ entity.pRetailPrize | number_format(2, ',', '') }}`